# Find maximum from complex hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have complex hash array and I am trying to find the maximum value from it. I contains two fields and I wish to extract only the highest value out of the data set.

Here is my hash:

```
hash = {
  0=>nil,
  1=>nil,
  2=>nil,
  3=>nil,
  4=>nil,
  5=>nil,
  6=>nil,
  7=>nil,
  8=>nil,
  9=>nil,
  10=>nil,
  11=>nil,
  12=>nil,
  13=>[{"name"=>"a", "value"=>6.3}],
  14=>[{"name"=>"b", "value"=>1.2}],
  15=>[{"name"=>"c", "value"=>2.5}],
  16=>[{"name"=>"d", "value"=>3.1}],
  17=>[{"name"=>"E", "value"=>1.2}],
  18=>[{"name"=>"f", "value"=>6.3}],
  19=>[{"name"=>"g", "value"=>3.9}],
  20=>[{"name"=>"h", "value"=>3.9}],
  21=>[{"name"=>"i", "value"=>3.9}],
  22=>nil,
  23=>nil
}
```

I am trying like this:

```
for t in 0..hash.size -1
 temp = hash[i].max_by{|a| a[0]["value"].to_i}
end
```

I only need the highest value from this hash, not even the tag.

The expected output should be only:

```
temp = 6.3
```

Comment: When you supply example/sample data, reduce it down to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that is a waste of our time and slows down and discourages answers.

Comment: What if all the values of the hash are nil? What value do you want returned?

Comment: This also works: `hash.to_s.scan(/(?<==>)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f).max => 6.3`.

Comment: This is a pure Ruby question, so I suggest you remove the Rails tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `nil` values are insignificant, I'd do something like:

```
hash = {
  0=>nil,
  12=>nil,
  13=>[{"name"=>"a", "value"=>6.3}],
  14=>[{"name"=>"b", "value"=>1.2}],
  15=>[{"name"=>"c", "value"=>2.5}],
  16=>[{"name"=>"d", "value"=>3.1}],
  17=>[{"name"=>"E", "value"=>1.2}],
  18=>[{"name"=>"f", "value"=>6.3}],
  19=>[{"name"=>"g", "value"=>3.9}],
  22=>nil,
  23=>nil
}

hash.values.select{ |v| v }.map{ |v| v.first['value'] }.max # => 6.3
```

If nils are significant, and it's possible to get both nil values or the hash-in-an-array, then I'd do something like:

```
hash = {
  0=>nil,
  18=>[{"name"=>"f", "value"=>6.3}],
}

hash.values.map{ |v| 
  Array === v ? v.first['value'] : -0.0
}.max # => 6.3
```

And I set the default `-0.0` to an obvious value that couldn't normally occur. It being returned would be an indicator that no other values were set.

---

> no this is returning the last value which is 3.9

That example output is directly out of my Ruby, so I know it works. Perhaps it's your Ruby version. Here's mine:

```
RUBY_VERSION # => "2.1.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
temp = hash.values.compact.flatten.map { |h| h["value"] }.max
```

Where `hash.values.compact` returns array of hash values with `nil` values removed.  The array is flattened and only the `value` key's value is retrieved by `.map { |h| h.fetch('value') }`, then `Enumerable#max` method is applied on the result array.

```
> hash = {0=>nil, 1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil, 5=>nil, 6=>nil, 7=>nil, 8=>nil, 9=>nil, 10=>nil, 11=>nil, 12=>nil, 13=>[{"name"=>"a", "value"=>6.3}], 14=>[{"name"=>"b", "value"=>1.2}], 15=>[{"name"=>"c", "value"=>2.5}], 16=>[{"name"=>"d", "value"=>3.1}], 17=>[{"name"=>"E", "value"=>1.2}], 18=>[{"name"=>"f", "value"=>6.3}], 19=>[{"name"=>"g", "value"=>3.9}], 20=>[{"name"=>"h", "value"=>3.9}], 21=>[{"name"=>"i", "value"=>3.9}], 22=>nil, 23=>nil}
> hash.values.flatten.compact.map { |h| h.fetch("value") }.max
=> 6.3
```